# Stanford CoreNLP is recognizing 2 seperate entities as the same when it shouldn't be

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

Heres the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "Loryn lives across the street from me. " 
                + "She is 19 years old. " 
                + "Sydney goes to my school. "
                + "She graduated last year. ";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,depparse,coref,kbp,quote");
        props.setProperty("coref.algorithm", "neural");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        CoreDocument document = new CoreDocument(text);
        pipeline.annotate(document);
        for (Entry<Integer, CorefChain> e : document.corefChains().entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getValue() + " - " + e.getKey());
            for (CorefMention s : e.getValue().getMentionsInTextualOrder()) {
                System.out.println(" - " + s);
            }
        }
```

Heres what the code outputs:

```
CHAIN7-["me" in sentence 1, "my" in sentence 3] - 7
 - "me" in sentence 1
 - "my" in sentence 3
CHAIN8-["Loryn" in sentence 1, "She" in sentence 2, "She" in sentence 4] - 8
 - "Loryn" in sentence 1
 - "She" in sentence 2
 - "She" in sentence 4
```

Why is `She` from the 4th sentence referring to Loryn? How can I make it refer to Sydney

The desired output should look similar to this:

```
CHAIN7-["me" in sentence 1, "my" in sentence 3] - 7
 - "me" in sentence 1
 - "my" in sentence 3
CHAIN8-["Loryn" in sentence 1, "She" in sentence 2] - 8
 - "Loryn" in sentence 1
 - "She" in sentence 2
CHAIN9-["Sydney" in sentence 3, "She" in sentence 4] - 8
 - "Sydney" in sentence 3
 - "She" in sentence 4
```

Answer (score 0):

"Sydney" is being tagged as the CITY so there is an NER error here.

That being said, it looks like it fails if you just change the name to "Jane" or something like that as well.

Unfortunately coreference is not really solved yet, and even state of the art systems make a lot of errors.  This is an interesting problem case though, we'll try to use this to add some more training data for the model in the future!